# What is the legacy ga.js equivalent of this analytics.js function?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking

In analytics.js you can set a custom property like so:

```
ga('set', 'foo', 'bar');
```

How to do this is the older legacy version?

### EDIT

I'm basically trying to do the equivalent of this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;
ga('set', 'dimension1',(ua.indexOf("FBAN") > -1) || (ua.indexOf("FBAV") > -1) ? 'Facebook' : 'None');
```

`dimension1` is something I got from the analytics dashboard when I created a 
"custom dimension". Following instructions from here not that it's relevant but still (http://oko.uk/blog/tracking-inapp-browsers).

So I'm not sure if this counts as a custom var...

Comment: Try it and see with the `_setCustomVar` API

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `_setCustomVar(index, name, value, opt_scope)` for creating a custom variable, like below -

```
 _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                   // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'Items Removed',     // The name acts as a kind of category for the user activity.  Required parameter.
      'Yes',               // This value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      2                    // Sets the scope to session-level.  Optional parameter.
   ]);
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',
      'Shopping', // category of activity
      'Item Removal', // Action
   ]);
```

Please check the following link for more details  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered good. Copy the most relevant information from the site, and then use the link for supporting information.

Comment: Thanks for this, can you please take a look at the edit and see if this is still what I should be using? I'm just not sure what to put for all those parameters since in the new analytics.js version I'm not using any of that.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think google even supports this anymore.

`_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', category, action, label]);`
You can read more in the documentation. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#one-push-multiple-commands